Как исправить ошибку. Необходимо находить мосты в графе. Реализация алгоритма
Решаю задачу на поиск мостов в неориентированном графе с возможными кратными ребрами и петлями. Необходимо посчитать и вывести количество мостов а также номера соответсвующих ребер в графе.
При рукписном тесте выдает ошибку
input:
1 2
2 1

ожидаемый output:
0
полученный output:
1 2 (1 - количество мостов, 2 - номер ребра, которое является мостом (порядок как в input)

Алгоритм:
    void DFS(int* checkedVert, int* h, int* low, int* bridge, int* countBridge, int v, int p, struct Adjacency* graph) {
    
        checkedVert[v] = 1;
    
        if (p == -1) {
            h[v] = 0;
            low[v] = 0;
        } else {
            h[v] = h[p] + 1;
            low[v] = h[p] + 1;
        }
    
        struct NodeGraph* Node = graph[v].head;
    
        while (Node != NULL) {
            if (Node->vert != p) {
                if (checkedVert[Node->vert]) {
                    // если ребро обратное
                    low[v] = myMin(low[v], h[Node->vert]);
                } else {
                    // если ребро прямое
                    DFS(checkedVert, h, low, bridge, countBridge, Node->vert, v, graph);
                    low[v] = myMin(low[v], low[Node->vert]);
                    if (h[v] < low[Node->vert]) {
                        //printf("%d %d\n", v, Node->vert);
                        bridge[(*countBridge)++] = Node->numb;
                    }
                }
            }
            Node = Node->next;
        }
    }

В одной учебной методичке с представленным алгоритмом нашел следующее:

"Если в графе могут быть кратные рёбра, необходимо запоминать не
родителя вершины, а идентификатор ребра, по которому мы пришли в
вершину, и пропускать в цикле только это ребро".

граф храню списком смежности:
struct NodeGraph {
    int vert;
    int numb;
    struct NodeGraph* next;
};

struct Adjacency {
    struct NodeGraph* head;
};


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
